# Downloading covid dataset from data.world using Python requests

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am trying to get the covid 19 Activity dataset from data.world into AWS S3 , for a data pipeline.

Myapproach so far:

1. Write a lambda function to get the data using python requests.get()
2. Store the content to s3 using csv writer.

However, while performing requests.get(), I get an html response.

Can someone please help me get the csv data and not the html.

https://data.world/covid-19-data-resource-hub/covid-19-case-counts

Thanks !

Comment: When I click the link, I get a page asking me to join. When you use `get()`, you are not logged in so you won't get the csv file.

Comment: Thanks @Mike67 for replicating my issue. I was able to do it by scrolling down , navigating to COVID-19 Activity.csv -> View -> copy link address -> make a python request.get() call to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

This site requires authentication. So firstly, authenticate yourself on the site by sending a user password pair, and then you can create a session, using `requests` `Session` object.

Once that is done, you can then try to imitate the actual requests which are used to download the dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Mooncrater for replicating my issue. I was able to do it by scrolling down , navigating to COVID-19 Activity.csv -> View -> copy link address -> make a python request.get() call to fetch the data.

Comment: @Jeet Glad to hear that!